# Radix sort incorrectly sorts an array of strings when they have different lengths

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, radix

So I'm currently attempting to sort a given array of strings in Java. I'm using radix sort to keep the time complexity at O(N+K). N is the length of the array and k is the length of all the characters. My intention was that the sorting algorithm should sort with numbers coming first in numeric order, and then alphabetically with any letters. So if the input array was `{"cd", "12", "ab"}`, the result of the sort would look like `{"12", "ab", "cd"}`. My issue comes in the form of handling strings of different lengths. To compensate for different lengths, I pre-processed the data by adding spaces to the end of each string to make every string the same length. However, in the actual sorting process, this causes the strings to be in the incorrect order. I've been debugging and I know the issue related to the sorting algorithm handling the artificial spaces. I use a hash map to determine the priority of all characters when it comes to the actual sorting. Not sure how to fix this. I tested it on an array of strings of the same length and it sorts correctly. So the issue is definitely with handling spaces. How do I fix it?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class StringSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {"apple", "beans", "cool5407", "algorithm", "number", "2021", "cs"};
        //String[] arr = {"34", "45", "23", "67","12", "ab", "56"};
        System.out.print("Initial Array: ");
        print(arr);
        radixSort(arr);
        
    }
    
    static void radixSort(String[] arr)
    {       
        /*If initial list has nothing in it, then ignore it.
         * If initial list has only 1 item in it, then its already sorted.
         * If it has more than 1 item, then sorting may be required. */      
        if(arr.length > 1)
        {
                        
            //Find Longest String
            int maxLength = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                if(arr[i].length() > maxLength)
                    maxLength = arr[i].length();
                
            }
            
            System.out.println("Max Length : " + maxLength);
            
            //Process Strings to make them all same length
            for(int STRIndex = 0; STRIndex < arr.length; STRIndex++)
            {
                if(arr[STRIndex].length() < maxLength)
                {
                    while(arr[STRIndex].length() < maxLength)
                    {
                        arr[STRIndex] = arr[STRIndex] + " ";
                    }
                    System.out.println("Remade String: [" + arr[STRIndex] + "] " + "Length: " + arr[STRIndex].length());
                }
                
            }
            
            //Sort by letter column via iterating
            for(int column = 0; column < maxLength; column++)
            {
                System.out.println("Sotring Column: " + column);
                countingSort(arr, column);
            }
            
            //Print Final Result
            System.out.print("Final Result: ");
            print(arr);
            
        }
    }// End of Radix Sort
    
    static void countingSort(String[] arr, int letterColumn)
    {
        int NUM_CHARACTERS = 37; //Number of Unique Characters that can be found in strings
        
        //Create Map to Map Letters to Numbers
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        //Map Numbers to Values (Higher Numbers belong in front)
        map.put(' ', 0); map.put('0',1); map.put('1',2); map.put('2',3); map.put('3',4); map.put('4',5); map.put('5',6); map.put('6',7); 
        map.put('7',8); map.put('8',9); map.put('9',10);
        //Map Letters to Values (Higher Numbers belong in front)
        map.put('a',11); map.put('b',12); map.put('c',13);  map.put('d',14); map.put('e',15); map.put('f',16); map.put('g',17); 
        map.put('h',18); map.put('i',19); map.put('j',20); map.put('k',21); map.put('l',22); map.put('m',23); map.put('n',24);
        map.put('o',25); map.put('p',26); map.put('q',27); map.put('r',28); map.put('s',29); map.put('t',30); map.put('u',31); 
        map.put('v',32);map.put('w',33); map.put('x',34); map.put('y',35); map.put('z',36); 
        
        String[] result = new String[arr.length];
        int[] count = new int[NUM_CHARACTERS];
        
        print(arr);
        
        
        //Store number of instances of each letter/number in a given column for each string
        for(int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++)
        {
            String currentString = arr[index];//Get Current String          
            int currentChar = map.get(currentString.charAt(letterColumn)); //Get int value of the Current Character
            count[currentChar]++; //Count the instance
            
        }
        
        //Edit count[index] so it contains position of digit in result
        for(int index = 1; index < NUM_CHARACTERS; index++)
        {
            count[index] += count[index-1];
        }
        
        //Create Result
        for(int index = arr.length - 1; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            String currentString = arr[index]; //Get Current String 
            int currentChar = map.get(arr[index].charAt(letterColumn)); //Get int value of the Current Character
            
            result[count[currentChar]-1] = arr[index]; //Set Character in Result to be sorted element
            count[currentChar]--;//Subtract from the current character count
            
        }
        
        //Override original arr[] to that it contains new array
        for(int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++)
        {
            arr[index] = result[index];
        }
        
    }//End of Counting Sort
    
    
    static void print(String[] arr)
    {
        System.out.print("[");
        //Print Final Result
        for(int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[index] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.print("]");
        System.out.println();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: How do I fix it

Comment: I might look into this in more detail later, but I will say that I have implemented radix sort in C++ and didn't have to do any string padding at all. It's been about a year and a half so I'm fuzzy on the details, but there's likely a more fundamental issue with your algorithm if you need to append spaces.

Comment: @mrpk, you need to count sort in reverse indices. i have added the working code as per your approach of adding spaces at end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues

The current code will not work for same length input too.

```java
String[] arr = {"11", "20"};
```

### Cause

```java
            //Sort by letter column via iterating
            for(int column = 0; column < maxLength; column++)
```

1. Current code moves from first(left) to last(right)
2. This will cause the current code to finally sort based on the last index(and hence will overwrite the changes done sofar).

### Suggestions

1. In every iteration of counting sort, the index should be moving from last(right) to first(left)
   The above code should be changed to

```java
//Sort by letter column via iterating in reverse order
for (int column = maxLength - 1; column >= 0; column--)
```

2. Or, if its required to move from left to right, then create subsegments based on so far sorted and recursively sort on those subsegments. (never change the order of initial characters)

### Working Simplified Code

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class StringSort {

    private final Map<Character, Integer> order;
    private final int charCount;

    public StringSort() {
        String characters = " 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        order = Collections.unmodifiableMap(IntStream.range(0, characters.length()).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(characters::charAt, Function.identity())));
        charCount = characters.length();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {"apple", "beans", "cool5407", "algorithm", "number", "2021", "cs"};
        StringSort stringSort = new StringSort();
        stringSort.radixSort(arr);
    }

    static void print(String prefix, String[] input) {
        System.out.println(prefix + Arrays.deepToString(input));
    }

    void radixSort(String[] input) {
        print("Initial Array: ", input);

        if (input.length < 2) {
            return;
        }

        int maxLength = Arrays.stream(input).map(s -> s.length())
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::intValue)).get();
        System.out.println("Max Length : " + maxLength);

        input = Arrays.stream(input)
            .map(s -> s + new String(new char[maxLength - s.length()])
                .replace("\0", " "))
            .toArray(String[]::new); // repeat " "
        print("Filled Array: ", input);

        //Sort by letter column via iterating
        for (int column = maxLength - 1; column >= 0; column--) {
            System.out.println("Sotring by column: " + column);
            countingSort(input, column);
            print("Updated State: ",  input);
        }
        print("Final Result: ", input);
    }

    void countingSort(String[] input, final int letterColumn) {
        final int stringCount = input.length;
        String[] result = new String[input.length];
        int[] counter = new int[charCount];

        Arrays.stream(input).map(s -> order.get(s.charAt(letterColumn))).forEach(c -> counter[c]++);

        IntStream.range(1, order.size()).forEach(i -> counter[i] += counter[i - 1]);

        for (int index = stringCount - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
            int currentChar = order.get(input[index].charAt(letterColumn));
            result[counter[currentChar] - 1] = input[index];
            --counter[currentChar];
        }

        IntStream.range(0, stringCount).forEach(i -> input[i] = result[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You were right, it was because I was doing sorting count starting from the first column, rather than starting from the last.

Comment: Thank you too for helping me refresh about `counting` and `radix` sort in Java.